# How to login through OpenID (MVC 4/Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I read several tutorials about [Dotnetopenauth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) but I still don't know how to login with OpenID.

To be more specific: I want to login on my site with the [Steam Service](http://steamcommunity.com/dev/) that uses OpenID, but I don't know how. I'm using C#/ASP.NET MVC 4/Razor.

Where I am now?

On **AuthConfig.cs** I have:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new OpenIdClient("Steam", 
                             "http://steamcommunity.com/openid"), "Steam", null);
```

... and I stopped! I don't know how to proceed! What I have to describe on login's view? What I have to describe on user's controller to identify that my provider is Steam, and not Google or Facebook?

I'm very confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should refer:

**[OAuth/OpenID Support for WebForms, MVC and WebPages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/15/oauth-openid-support-for-webforms-mvc-and-webpages.aspx)**:
One of the coolest features in Visual Studio 2012 is the ability to login using your Microsoft, Facebook, Twitter or Google account. **The project templates showcase a social way of logging in along with the usual way of logging in by creating a local account**

This post highlights how you can turn on support for logging through these services in the project  templates.

Comment: Coincidently I looked this topic just right now. Unfortunately, still not clearly for me. I think it will not to the point.

Comment: Oh, I finally got it! Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate or include your code Guilherme? I am still struggling to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can't login **to** Steam using the built-in authentication providers.
If supported by Steam, you should be able to logon to **your own site** using Steam as authentication provider, but judging from your post, that's the other way around.

Comment: Oh, Hanno. You're right — I've expressed myself badly. I edited the main post to the right way. Thanks!